# See/View different meaning example

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I am not sure when I should use in the sentence "see" or "view".

If I want to say for example: My teachers see/view giving lectures to me as a waste of time. What is more correct please?

See feels more natural to me but viewing is like giving an introspective, right?

Comment: View implies opinion more than see - as in point of view.

Comment: So see is more physical/concrete? In my native language we have only one expression so it is confusing for me.

Comment: No, not necessarily. But view carries a meaning of judgement where see can mean simple observation without analysis/judgement.

Comment: Well that is tricky, in my example for example.

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  Can you give more examples of when you feel the difference in see vs view?

Comment: So another example: How people see me? Vs How people view me? And I mean as a personality, not visually. Which is better?

Comment: I would say *view* implies more intent.  I can *see* an image without intending to see it; I cannot *view* an image without intent.  In my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course *see* and *view* both have the literal meaning of physically looking at something.  Either verb can also be used metaphorically, as you are doing, in the sense of having a particular opinion of something. I don't think it matters much which one you use. *View* as a noun can also mean an opinion, so maybe the verb is slightly weighted in that direction.